# Noip not working on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, server, apache2, dns

I have used noip on windows, it's a great tool.

I have also installed it on ubuntu 12.10, but it seems to be not working somehow. I have apache installed on my machine, I start it with

> /etc/init.d/apache2 start

and then I can see apache's that "It works!" webpage on localhost:80.

Then I start noip client with

> sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2

where it says

> Can't locate configuration file /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf. (Try -c). Ending!

so then when I start it with -C as

> $ sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2 -C
>
> Auto configuration for Linux client of no-ip.com.
>
> Please enter the login/email string for no-ip.com  MY-EMAIL-ID
>
> Please enter the password for user 'MY-EMAIL-ID'  MY-PASSWORSD
>
> Only one host [MYHOSTNAME.no-ip.org] is registered to this account.
>
> It will be used.
>
> Please enter an update interval:[30]
>
> Do you wish to run something at successful update?[N] (y/N)
>
> New configuration file '/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf' created.

Then I suppose the noip client should get started.
I check if it's started by

> ps -A | grep noip

which shows, something like

> 5498 ?        00:00:00 noip2

but then when I check in a browser using **MYHOSTNAME.no-ip.org** or **MYHOSTNAME.no-ip.org:80**, it just doesn't open that apache page.
I tried with tomcat server as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your apache server listens only at localhost by default. In the directory `/etc/apache2/` you'll find the configuration files. Look for the line

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

and change it to

```
Listen 80
```

Now you should restart the Apache process and the server listens also on public interfaces.

There might also be the chance that your internet router does not forward the packages to Apache. In this case you'll have to change the setup in your router so that packages to port 80 get forwarded to the Apache IP address.

Comment: I checked above mentioned apache setting, it is *:80. And, I am able to use my IP address, I can see apache page with my IP address in browser. About router, I am using android mobile tethering :( , which used to work with Windows7. I used to use that connection to use No-IP on Windows7.